# How to automatically run Node.js server on Apache with Shell Script

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, shell-scripting, ubuntu-16.04, autoscaling

I usually access my application via Putty and do exactly what I show below to let my Node script running in the background:

```
screen
cd /var/www/node
node app.js
```

I'm using Ubuntu and I have already created an AMI of my instance and now I intend to use it in my Auto Scaling configuration, however, how should I do this Lauch Configuration in Shell Script so when I create a new instance it will automatically run my Node application?

The only thing I know is that I should start with `#!/bin/bash`, but I don't know how to write the rest the correct way.

```
#!/bin/bash
screen
cd /var/www/node
node app.js
```

If I use it as I showed above, will it work normally or should I do it any other way? If so, can you give an example?

**Update**:
Following [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) comment, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service/29042953#29042953). So my code looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=To run Node

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/node/app.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
Group=nobody
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/node

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when trying to run the service with `systemctl start app` It asks for an authentication:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'app.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:
```

However, this user does not have a password (not that I know of), so I just hit enter and he gives the following error:

```
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start app.service: Access denied
```

So, I tried with `sudo systemctl start app`, but it's like nothing happened. How can I run this service?

After running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, `sudo systemctl start app` and `sudo systemctl status app`, is returned:

```
● app.service - App
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: Stopped App.
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: Started App.
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[7645]: app.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /var/www/node/app.js: No such process
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: Stopped App.
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 10 01:15:47 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: Failed to start App.
```

**Update²**:
I've changed the `app.service` to (removed the `Group` directive and added the `node` to run):

```
[Unit]
Description=App

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs /var/www/node/app.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/node

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But, when I access the status, is shown:

```
● app.service - App
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 nodejs[8084]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 nodejs[8084]:     at startup (node.js:136:18)
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 nodejs[8084]:     at node.js:966:3
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: Stopped App.
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: app.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 10 02:13:37 ip-172-31-12-252 systemd[1]: Failed to start App.
```

Comment: Write a simple systemd unit to start and manage the app.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated my question following your comment.

Comment: OK, so check its status.

Comment: @MichaelHampton status in question

Comment: Aren't you supposed to call node to start node.js?

Comment: Do you mean `ExecStart=node /var/www/node/app.js` instead of `ExecStart=/var/www/node/app.js`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton updated again

Answer (score 1):

Your script will block execution, so AT VERY LEAST you should send NodeJS process to background:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/node
nohup node app.js >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That'll work provided that your AMI has already `nohup` and `node` installed.

Bash scripts are only gonna bring you so far. If you're serious about deployment in AWS I would suggest learning either `cloud-init` or Chef/OpsWorks.

http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/

https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/